# Field 'x' doesn't have a default value in PHP 7 version

Tags: php, mysql

I got an error

> #1364 - Field 'login_count' doesn't have a default value

Recently upgraded php 5.5 to  php 7. After upgrading it is showing an error. I have the table columns below.
`firstname`, `middlename`, `lastname`, `username`, `password`, `email`, `mobile`, `added_date`,`login_count`, `status`

and when I'm inserting in table data getting below error.

```
INSERT INTO `js_simple`
       (`firstname`, `middlename`, `lastname`, `username`, `password`, `email`, 
        `mobile`, `added_date`) 
VALUES ('Kjhjkh', 'Jkjhjkhk', 'Jkhkjhj', 'jkhjkh', 'khkjh', 'njhjhjkh@gmail.com', 
        '1122335566', '2017-11-29 22:59:49')
```

> #1364 - Field 'login_count' doesn't have a default value

Here `login_count` and `status` fields are not inserting and default value not null in table.

Before upgrading into php7 it's working. Can any one help me on this please.

Comment: Set a default value for it, This is due to the STRICT_TRANS_TABLES SQL mode defined in the your mysql

Comment: What is the `CREATE TABLE` definition for `js_simple`? It looks like `login_count` doesn't have a default value defined, meaning you have to provide it with `INSERT` statements.

Comment: Yes Absolutely correct your answer , But my doubt is how its work's previous version with out giving default value in `INSERT` statement ?? Thanks ...

Answer (score 1):

```
SET GLOBAL sql_mode = 'NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION';
```

Note that you must have root permissions.

Explanation:

Strict mode controls how MySQL handles invalid or missing values in data-change statements such as INSERT or UPDATE. A value can be invalid for several reasons. For example, it might have the wrong data type for the column, or it might be out of range. A value is missing when a new row to be inserted does not contain a value for a non-NULL column that has no explicit DEFAULT clause in its definition. (For a NULL column, NULL is inserted if the value is missing.) Strict mode also affects DDL statements such as CREATE TABLE. (source and in more detail: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sql-mode-strict )

Regarding the query - it changes the SQL mode to NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION which is:

Control automatic substitution of the default storage engine when a statement such as CREATE TABLE or ALTER TABLE specifies a storage engine that is disabled or not compiled in. (source: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_no_engine_substitution)

In other words, the strict mode is disabled when the command is given to disable all substitutions, in particular - the strict mode engine.

Note that ideally, it's a good practice to have the strict mode on as it helps the developer to create a perfectly working system and quite well reduces the server load. But it creates errors in some cases that might be missed during debugging process, thus "breaking down" the whole application when users stumble upon those errors.